# AppEngine remote API keeps returning 302

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to download a datastore from my appengine application. The application itself is written in JAVA and I've already activated remote API according to [this instruction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi?hl=pl&csw=1). Then I run `appcfg.py` and it asks me for log in details and I get the following result:

```
06:18 PM Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20131101.181851
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Please enter login credentials for [_app_address_]    
Email: [_My_Google_Mail_]
Password for [_My_Google_Mail_]: 
Error 302: --- begin server output ---

--- end server output ---
```

Obviously I've hidden app and my mail but they are correct (I use the same credentials when use appcfg.sh to deploy new version).

If it helps the app configuration is:
Authentication Type: (Experimental) Federated Login
Datastore Replication Options: High Replication

What can I do about it?? I really need to get local copy of the production data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh. The problem was in `Note: Bulk upload and download is not supported for apps that use Federated (OpenID) authentication`

I made a workaround - maybe someone finds it useful. To download data I've created a second app with google account authentication type and uploaded simple python app from [this instruction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#a_note_for_java_developers). This way I was able to move entities from my source app to target and then download it using simple `appcfg.py` call...

Answer (score 0):

```
The parameter `--url` needs to start with `https`
e.g.
`appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --url=https://<APP_ID>.appspot.com/remote_api --kind=<ENTITY> --filename=<FILE_NAME>.csv`
```